# I can not created sitemap.xml site 10000pages use codeigniter

Tags: sitemap

I have a website of about 10,000 pages. I use the codeigniter. it is difficult to create a sitemap.xml. I ask for your guidance:
i want to guide full sourcecode auto updates the sitemap, run auto daily and auto create sitemap.xml!
i hope help from friends! so thanks!

Comment: You'd want to research and look for tutorials on sitemap index to break apart your sitemap into smaller chunks.

Comment: no. i have not sitemap.xml for site at this time. i want to create us

Answer (score 0):

Look into organizing your links using a sitemap index style sitemap.xml. Since you said it's hard to manage, break it up into easier to manage chunks and use a sitemap index to connect them. This should give you a better idea of how to approach the subject - https://dynomapper.com/blog/16-sitemap-generator/165-managing-large-websites-with-multiple-sitemaps